# How to create a parent group totals based on different child group

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, reporting

I'm not sure if I'm phrasing this correctly...

I need help splitting a total to have multi-rows/columns inside a total;
or another way to say this is, I need to have a parent group total with based on different child group.

Please see the picture below:

[image]

I am using matrix element for my stepped report. I have 4 tiers of groups on the Y-axis, and 3 tiers of groups on X-axis. On the y-axis, I have created totals for my tier 2 - Products (Linked/non-par) and totals for my tier 3 - products (A / B).

However, for the tier 3 - products (A / B) total, I need to split that total into total-A and total-B, so that the accumulative total values (66800) would be split into the sum of product A and sum of products B.

I'd like to do this without using expressions if possible. But if there are no solution, I'm open to Expression or changing dataset w/ T-SQL (if necessary).

Any ideas?!

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? Tag appropriate pls

Comment: It's not totally clear what your are trying to do. Is this subgroup only present under the `Linked`Product or also under `Non-Par`? Can you just add a child group?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the desired result is.  Are you talking about having the rows show Total A, Total B, A - Season 1, A - Season 2, B - Season 1, etc?  If so:  Just insert an adjacent group before Products (A/B) group, also grouping on Products (A/B).  Then use that group to display the totals.

Comment: I found the answer already, thx. And for those whose also lookin for similar problem, the keyword is add adjacent group, then add child group on the adjacent group.